# How to format output numbers like 0.?

Tags: formatting, output

I have a function which is given below. If my number, n is 0. or 1. the function gives 0.E0 or 1.E0, respectively. However, I would like to form it as 0.0000E0 or 1.0000E0 like the other numbers given in the function. How could I solve this problem ?

```
f[n_] := ScientificForm[N[n], NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[#3 == "", "0", #3]}] &)];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
Clear[f]
f[n_, w_Integer /; Positive[w]] :=
  PaddedForm[N[n], {w, w},
    NumberPadding -> {"", "0"},
    NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[#3 == "", "0", #3]}] &)]
```

Then

```
f[#, 2] & /@ Range[0, 1, .25]
```

> `{0.00e0, 0.25e0, 0.50e0,0.75e0, 1.00e0}`

and

```
f[#, 5] & /@ Range[0, 1, .25]
```

> `{0.00000e0, 0.25000e0, 0.50000e0, 0.75000e0, 1.00000e0}`